# Return a list of attribute values using Beautiful Soup

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm doing a small project to scrape some data of a specific attribute, from this HTML:

```html
  <players>
    <player username="Vac19" userid="2097691" name="Victor Carmona" startposition="" color="" score="9" new="0" rating="0" win="0"/>
    <player username="" userid="0" name="Crystal Carmona" startposition="" color="" score="10" new="0" rating="0" win="1"/>
    <player username="" userid="0" name="Cj" startposition="" color="" score="8" new="0" rating="0" win="0"/>
  </players>
```

End

How do I extract the values from the Score attribute using Beautiful Soup such as I get a list Score = [9, 10, 8]?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list comprehension:

```
scores = [tag['score'] for tag in soup.find_all('player')]

print(scores)
```

Output:

```
['9', '10', '8']
```